Can I negotiate garden leave with my tech boss?
My European employer is undergoing a transformation.
During this process I attempted to negotiate which team I got and then my line manager dropped a bomb about him not being satisfied with my performance compared to other leaders. He said I need to up my game, be more present in the office and take on more overarching topics.
However, my teams are producing the best outcomes according to stakeholders which I told him. So I disagree that I am underperforming.
It transpired that he ranked the performance of the leaders and then the leaders with the highest performance were allowed to choose which teams they want to lead first. Some like me were assigned to teams with no negotiation and the rest were fired.
My line manager never indicated that there was a problem with my performance for half a decade before this event.
Yes I am grateful I didn’t get fired.
I see three options:

Making most of new team and doing my best
1 + looking for another job and resigning
Asking for garden leave is really my question for this forum.

Since my manager obviously considers me a low performer it probably would be best if I just left.
My question is, could I negotiate garden leave at this point:
Tell him I will disappear if he pays 6 months severance.
The reasoning is I don’t speak the local language and I am going to have a hell of a time finding a new job and might have to move back to an English country.

@user32613 Giving you a poor rating is not the same as what happened at Twitter.

What is your country (i.e. where you live)?

Management has told you that you are underperforming for your role, whether or not your team is performing well. Ask for details and guidance in fixing that. Leaving may not be the right response.

No, don't ask for gardening leave. You won't get it. Unless you have a particularly weird contract that prevents them from simply firing you, the company has absolutely no reason to pay you to do nothing; that's worse for them than either paying you to continue to underperform or firing you outright.
If you want to job hunt rather than (or, better, in addition to) trying to improve your evaluation at this company, do so on your own time.


Tell him I will disappear if he pays 6 months severance and I won’t say anything disparaging to anyone?

If you walk into my (virtual) office and say that, a number of things will happen:

I'll ask you to take the rest of the day off and think about things.
I'll contact HR and Legal.
You can expect a letter from HR terminating your employment with immediate effect, and a letter from Legal reminding you of the consequences of defamation.

Don't threaten your employer (even implicitly) unless you intend to act on it, they have bigger sticks than you do.

I have rephrased my question as this is not what I want help with.

"You can expect a letter from HR terminating your employment with immediate effect" that would only work in the US or other countries with laws that don't protect workers. In most states in Europe, this wouldn't fly without documented gross misconduct of the OP, and would effectively mean they do put him on gardening leave for as long as the notice period, and maybe even longer if OP would legally challenge it.

@MarkRotteveel badly formed extortion counts as cause usually.

@AidaPaul That can easily be legally challenged as malicious interpretation by the employer, because non-disparagement clauses are absolutely normal in contract severance agreements.

@MarkRotteveel not if the remarks are entirely made up, and given op "clarification" that's likely what's going on. But also this isn't the place for effect specific details of one case, is it? Just that making extortion that's to current boss is a bad idea and absolutely can lead to instant termination, when in countries with strong employment laws (thus why in the answer your have consulting legal first).

@AidaPaul I think you're reading too much between the lines there (though granted, I may be giving the OP too much benefit of the doubt). I don't see an extortion attempt here, and given non-disparagement clauses are normal, bringing it up in an attempt to negotiate a severance agreement is also normal, so an employer using that to fire someone effective immediately can be construed as constructive dismissal, giving the OP legal ammunition to challenge their dismissal.

The most dignified way is to either work until you have lined up the new job and give notice, or give notice and accept that you may be out of work for a while while job hunting, or to work with your manager to improve your performance.


Since my manager obviously considers me a low performer it probably would be best if I just left.

I'm not sure your manager views you as a low performer, just not a star.

he ranked the performance of the leaders and then the leaders with the highest performance were allowed to choose which teams they want to lead first. Some like me were assigned to teams with no negotiation and the rest were fired.

This implies to me that you are viewed as somewhere in the middle of your peers.  You aren't a high enough performer to get to choose your own team but neither are you a low performer - you'd have been dismissed in that case.
It sounds like your boss is satisfied with you work. No more, no less.  Given that you feel you'd struggle to find a new job, I'd suggest your option 1 - Making most of new team and doing my best.  If you're disappointed not to be viewed as a star employee, ask for feedback on what it'd take to move into this bracket.
I appreciate this doesn't answer your question so far.  You should not ask for garden leave.  While this would benefit you, your employer has absolutely no incentive to offer you 6 months of paid holiday / job hunting.
